# How to iterate by batches in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, collections

I have this function that does stuff with numbers between a start and end date. The problem is, if I have like a large collection of numbers (say, over 1 million numbers), then I want to batch the mongodb collection to read more efficiently. This code makes batches of size 100, but how do I iterate through the batches? And how can I see how many batches there are? For example, if every 5th batch, I wanted to do something differently, how would I achieve this? Thanks.

```
function someFunc(start, end) {
  let batches = db.collection('my collection').find({
    $and: [
      { number: { $gte: start } },
      { number: { $lte: end } }
    ]
  })
  .batchSize(100)
  .toArrayAsync()
  .then(messages => {//do stuff});

  return batches;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB [cursors](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html) offer a slice index, but you would need otherwise to write a function that continuously creates batches.

There is a [`batch_size()`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.batch_size) method, but you would still need to iterate over each item. This function helps with performance and can decrease the number of round trips to the server.